# How to change web part property values

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

In a SharePoint 2007 web part, I want to delete an existing property and replace it with a property using a different name. I want to get the value from the existing property and assign it to the new property.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

**In summary:**

- Get a reference to the page containing the web part.
- Get a reference to the web part itself.
- Change the property value.
- Save the change.

**In code:**

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepoint"))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("Web Title"))
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager =
       web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared))
{
    try
    {
        foreach (WebPart webPart in webPartManager.WebParts)
        {
            if ((webPart.Title == "Web Part Title") && (!webPart.IsClosed))
            {
                YourWebPart wp = (YourWebPart)webPart;
                wp.NewProperty = wp.OldProperty;
                webPartManager.SaveChanges(wp);
                web.Update();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        webPartManager.Web.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Replace the following in this code example:

- **"http://sharepoint"** - the address of your SharePoint site
- **"Web Title"** - the title of the SharePoint web containing the web part to be changed (or use one of the other OpenWeb overloads
- **"default.aspx"** - filename of the page containing the web parts
- **"Web Part Title"** - title given to the web part on the page
- **YourWebPart** - class name of the web part to change
- **NewProperty/OldProperty** - names of the properties to change

Comment: is this needed if I want to change the property value inside the web part? I'm submitting a Modal Dialog that refresh the web part editing page. I can get that value on PreRender or any other function and I would like to save that value on a custom property that I created.